# Unable to integrate docusign with third party application

Tags: docusignapi

I have created Docusign Sandbox account for testing purposes . I want to integrate it with my third party application to check how the things will work . But when i am trying to integrate with my application by entering the username , password and account id then it shows an error message that " Docusign denied access to its login api"  Can you please help me in this.

Do i need a paid docusign account for integration ? Can i do it without paid account by using Docusign sandbox feature

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can completely build and test your integration by using a free DocuSign Sandbox account available via this [signup form](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/).

Then check out the [getting started section of the DevCenter website](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides) for suggested next steps.

Got specific questions about integrating? Check Google and if you don't see an answer, ask a new question here on StackOverflow.

Thank you for integrating with DocuSign.